# Pegar valor input sempre que alterado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho um elemento:

```
<input id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="3" type="number">
```

onde eu guardo o valor dele numa variável:

```
var qty = $('#quantity').val();
```

por padrão o valor é 1.

Gostaria que sempre que alterado a quantidade desse `input` ele atualizasse em tempo real a variável `qty` pois vou passa-lo como parâmetro em outra função em uma URL, exmeplo:

```
$('meu-botao').attr('href','/busca/quantidade='+qty).
```

Utilizei a função:

```
var qty = 0;
$('#quantity').on('change keyup paste click',function() {
    qty = $(this).val();
});
```

Mas ao fazer isso o novo valor da variavel `qty` não é atualizada em tempo real no atributo `href` do meu botão.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente utilizer o `.keyup()`, isso irá inserir no link no momento em que digitar qualquer número.

Teste isso aqui:

```js
$('#quantity').keyup(function () {
  
  // Se não for número muda para nada 
  if(!$.isNumeric($(this).val())){
     $(this).val('');   
  }
  
  // Se for maior que máximo altera para o máximo
  if($(this).val() > $(this).attr('max')){
     $(this).val( $(this).attr('max') );   
  }
  
  // Se for menor que o minimo (mas diferente de nada, porque se apagar é nada) muda para o minimo
  if($(this).val() < $(this).attr('min') && $(this).val() != ''){
     $(this).val( $(this).attr('min') );   
  }
  
  // Se for diferente de nada ele muda o link para o obtido
  // Se for igual ao nada o link não será modificado
  if($(this).val() != ''){
     qty = $(this).val();
  }
  
  // Insere o link como TEXT, altere isto!
  // Apenas para visualização!
  $('demostracao').text('/busca/quantidade='+qty);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="3" type="text" value="1">
<br>
<demostracao></demostracao>
```

A função básica, sem as correções extras, esta aqui:

```
$('#quantity').keyup(function () {
  qty = $(this).val();
  $('meu-botao').attr('href','/busca/quantidade='+qty);
}
```

O `keyup` irá executar a função sempre que a tecla é solta, mas isso não exige que o usuário saia do campo ou clique fora da tela, como no caso do `.on('change')` mencionado.

Answer (score 4):

Apenas adicione o valor diretamente dessa forma:

```
$('meu-botao').attr('href','/busca/quantidade='+$('#quantity').val())
```

Assim sempre pegará o valor atual do elemento `quantity`.

Uma pergunta, não relacionada com o foco da pergunta, por que não usa apenas "change"?

```
$('#quantity').on('change keyup paste click',function() {
```

Ficaria assim:

```
$('#quantity').on('change',function() {
```

Pois se o intuito é pegar somente quando modifica, o evento `change` é  suficiente, independente de como provier a alteração.

Agora, continuando com o foco da questão, se, com a mudança sugerida `$('#quantity').val()`, a variável `qty` não for mais usada, o evento `change` deixa de ter sentido. Poderia eliminar esse trecho do código.

[edit]

Exemplo completo:

```
$('#quantity').on('change',function() {
    $('meu-botao').attr('href','/busca/quantidade='+$('#quantity').val());
}
```

Comment: Show não tinha pensado nisso, vou testar da forma que citou.

`'change keyup paste click'` usei após várias tentativas frustradas haha inclusive vi em uma questão do stack em inglês.

Comment: não funcionou :( Eu preciso que seja atualizado em tempo real no dom no caso no href do botão também, pois estou usando uma plataforma saca?

Comment: não sei como fez.. não posso dizer nada.. na prática deveria funcionar.  coloquei um exemplo completo...

Answer (score 2):

Acho que dessa forma deve funcionar:

```
<input id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="3" type="number">
<div id="divRetorno"></div>

<script>
$('#quantity').on('change',function() {
    qty = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: "/busca/quantidade="+qty,
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result)
            $("#divRetorno").html(result);
        }
    });

});
</script>
```